# Need better UI representation of comparing two data source

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, layout

Looking for good UI representation of showing differences in each ROW between two different two data source. One data source is Source Data and another is transformed data (destination) which is more or else same data as Source Data Source. I would need some design concept of showing differences between two data source columns in UI. I thinking of showing with 2 grids where left is source data and right is Destination data and highlight the column wise cell for showing difference.

Please let me know design of UI about the differences.

-Mahens

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you be more specific?  Who are your users?  What will they hope to accomplish with this interface?  Can you give a concrete example of what you have so far and ask about a specific element of it?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I haven't checked back site , we 2 sql tables, one is source and other is modified , I just need to show differences column wise compare on UI. Where Left side contains source data and right side contains modified data and highlight the modified cell.

Answer (score 1):

Kompare has a nice interface for comparing rows of text. It shows different colors for insertions, deletions, and changes between the two data files. If you export your data to text, you may be able to use a visual diff tool like Kompare directly instead of writing your own software.

[image: Kompare screen shot]